# Rails loading initializer classes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, initializer

In my Rails app, I created an initalizer which responsability is to:

1. Require the service layer of my app

   `Dir[File.expand_path('services/*.rb',\__FILE__)].each { |file| require file }`
2. Create those services and inject dependencies in it

But now, when I update a file in my project in development my rails server starts complaning that classes are not available anymore.

To make it work I have to delete my tmp directory and **run rails server again** to have it work again.

How can I work around that ?

Answer (score 0):

Which tmp/ directory ? what is there in it ?

The reboot is not a surprise since you're using initializers. They are loaded once on boot and that's it.

Maybe https://github.com/guard/guard could help you reload the env automaticaly.

Maybe it's not initializers you're looking for ...

The answer depends on what you're trying to achieve. This is more an architectural problem than a code/dev one tough.

Comment: tmp directory is my local cache directory

Answer (score 0):

I think a better solution to creating an initializer to load those files is to use the following syntax in your application.rb file:

```
module AppName
  class Application < Rails::Application
    #other config stuff here
    config.eager_load_paths << "path to your services directory"
  end
end
```

This will make rails reload the files for every request in development mode, as well as requiring them normally in production mode.